# DirectoryInfo output, directories missing

Tags: c#, subdirectory, directoryinfo

I'm trying to use `DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories()` to look up every directory under a given path.

The problem is that it seems to work OK, there are no errors other then the `UnauthorizedAccess Exception` when it tries reading from `System Volume Information` but still at the end of all that it's missing directories.

According to TotalCMD (using the properties option) my D:\ Drive has 4580 directories, According to Windows Explorer it has 4574 and according to my program it has 4566...

I've tried everything i could think of. Checking the DIR-s one by one, emptying the recycle bin, including hidden directories manually, but nothing seems to make a difference. Also that'S not just on my D drive as well...

Is that a common bug or is there a reason?

(Just mentioning that I'm learning c# completely by myself so my methods for doing stuff are probably completely wrong, it's just how i get past the things i don't know yet)

EDIT: All my Code:

FindDirectories.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WolfPaw_Duplicate_Search_and_Destroy
{
    class FindDirectories
    {
        DirectoryInfo[] tempDirectoryInfo;
        DirectoryInfo[] fullDirectoryInfo;
        String tmpDirInfo = "";
        String tmpDirInfo2 = "";
        String[] fullDirInfo = new String[1000000];
        DirectoryInfo[] dinf = new DirectoryInfo[100];

        public DirectoryInfo[] getDirectories(DirectoryInfo[] dinf)
        {
            tempDirectoryInfo = dinf;

            GetDirectories();

            return fullDirectoryInfo;
        }



        private void GetDirectories()
        {
            try
            {
                int index = 0;
                try
                {
                    foreach (DirectoryInfo dinf in tempDirectoryInfo)
                    {
                        if (dinf != null)
                            foreach (DirectoryInfo dd in dinf.GetDirectories())
                            {
                                if (dd != null)
                                {
                                    tmpDirInfo += dd.FullName + "♣";
                                    index++;
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("Current working directories: " + tmpDirInfo + Environment.NewLine + "Error Message: " + ex.Message); }

                tmpDirInfo2 += tmpDirInfo;

                tempDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo[index];

                index = 0;
                foreach (String s in tmpDirInfo.Split('♣'))
                {
                    if (s.Length > 0)
                        tempDirectoryInfo[index] = new DirectoryInfo(s);
                    index++;
                }

                tmpDirInfo = "";

                int i = 0;
                foreach (DirectoryInfo x in tempDirectoryInfo)
                {
                    if (x != null)
                        i++;
                }

                if (tempDirectoryInfo.Length != 0)
                {
                    GetDirectories();
                }
                else
                {
                    StringToDirInfo(tmpDirInfo2);
                }

            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            { }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }


        }

        private void StringToDirInfo(String s_dInfo)
        {
            int index = 0;

            foreach (String s in s_dInfo.Split('♣'))
            {
                index++;
            }

            fullDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo[index];

            index = 0;
            foreach (String s in s_dInfo.Split('♣'))
            {
                if (s.Length > 0)
                {
                    fullDirectoryInfo[index] = new DirectoryInfo(s);
                    index++;
                }
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WolfPaw_Duplicate_Search_and_Destroy
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
            public Form1()
            {
                    InitializeComponent();

                    foreach(String s in Environment.GetLogicalDrives())
                    {
                            DriveInfo dinf1 = new DriveInfo(s);

                            try
                            {
                                    if(dinf1.DriveType != DriveType.CDRom)
                                    {
                                            textBox_Dirs.Text += s + "||";
                                    }
                            }
                            catch { }
                    }

                    comboBox_Larger.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    comboBox_Smaller.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }

            private void button_DirResize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    if (textBox_Dirs.Height < 100)
                    {
                            textBox_Dirs.Height = 100;
                            textBox_Dirs.Multiline = true;
                            button_DirResize.Top = textBox_Dirs.Bottom - (button_DirResize.Height / 2); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            textBox_Dirs.Height = 20;
                            textBox_Dirs.Multiline = false;
                            button_DirResize.Top = textBox_Dirs.Bottom - (button_DirResize.Height / 2); 
                    }

                    textBox_FileTypes.Top = textBox_Dirs.Bottom + 15;
                    comboBox_Filetypes.Top = textBox_FileTypes.Top;
                    label_FyleType.Top = textBox_FileTypes.Top + ((textBox_FileTypes.Height / 2) - (label_FyleType.Height / 2));
                    button_FileTypeResize.Top = textBox_FileTypes.Bottom - (button_FileTypeResize.Height / 2);
            }

            private void comboBox_Filetypes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    if (comboBox_Filetypes.SelectedItem.ToString().Contains("*.*") == false)
                    {
                            if (textBox_FileTypes.Text.Contains("*.*; "))
                            {
                                    textBox_FileTypes.Text = textBox_FileTypes.Text.Replace("*.*; ", "");
                            }
                            else if (textBox_FileTypes.Text.Contains("*.*;"))
                            {
                                    textBox_FileTypes.Text = textBox_FileTypes.Text.Replace("*.*;", "");
                            }
                            else if (textBox_FileTypes.Text.Contains("*.*"))
                            {
                                    textBox_FileTypes.Text = textBox_FileTypes.Text.Replace("*.*", "");
                            }

                    }

                    textBox_FileTypes.Text += comboBox_Filetypes.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(comboBox_Filetypes.SelectedItem.ToString().IndexOf("(") + 1).Replace(")","") + "; ";
            }

            private void textBox_FileTypes_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    if(textBox_FileTypes.Text.Contains("*.*"))
                    {
                            textBox_FileTypes.Text = "*.*;";
                    }
                    else if(textBox_FileTypes.Text.Contains("; ; "))
                    {
                            textBox_FileTypes.Text = textBox_FileTypes.Text.Replace("; ; ","; ");
                    }
                    else if (textBox_FileTypes.Text.Contains(";; "))
                    {
                            textBox_FileTypes.Text = textBox_FileTypes.Text.Replace(";; ", "; ");
                            textBox_FileTypes.SelectionStart = textBox_FileTypes.Text.Length;
                            textBox_FileTypes.Select();
                    }
            }

            private void button_FileTypeResize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    if (textBox_FileTypes.Height < 100)
                    {
                            textBox_FileTypes.Height = 100;
                            textBox_FileTypes.Multiline = true;
                            button_FileTypeResize.Top = textBox_FileTypes.Bottom - (button_FileTypeResize.Height / 2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            textBox_FileTypes.Height = 20;
                            textBox_FileTypes.Multiline = false;
                            button_FileTypeResize.Top = textBox_FileTypes.Bottom - (button_FileTypeResize.Height / 2);
                            label_FyleType.Top = textBox_FileTypes.Top + ((textBox_FileTypes.Height / 2) - (label_FyleType.Height / 2));
                    }

                    textBox_FileTypes.Top = textBox_Dirs.Bottom + 15;
                    comboBox_Filetypes.Top = textBox_FileTypes.Top;

            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    if (label_FileBeingChecked.Height < 100)
                    {
                            label_FileBeingChecked.Height = 100;
                            button1.Text = "↑";
                            button1.Cursor = Cursors.PanNorth;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            label_FileBeingChecked.Height = 24;
                            button1.Text = "↓";
                            button1.Cursor = Cursors.PanSouth;
                    }

                    progressBar1.Top = label_FileBeingChecked.Bottom + 2;
                    label_FNumber.Top = progressBar1.Bottom + 4;
                    label_NumOfFiles.Top = progressBar1.Bottom + 4;
            }

            private void button_Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    FolderBrowserDialog ofd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
                    DialogResult dres = ofd.ShowDialog();

                    if(dres == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                            textBox_Dirs.Text += ofd.SelectedPath + "||";
                    }
            }

            private void button_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    StartSearch();
            }

            public void StartSearch()
            {
                    //Get Directory List

                    FindDirectories fd = new FindDirectories();

                    int index = 0;

                    String[] s_Dirs = textBox_Dirs.Text.Replace("||","↓").Split('↓');

                    DirectoryInfo[] di = new DirectoryInfo[s_Dirs.Length];

                    foreach(String s in s_Dirs)
                    {
                            if(s.Length != 0)
                            di[index] = new DirectoryInfo(s);
                            index++;
                    }

                    DirectoryInfo[] dinfo = fd.getDirectories(di);

                    int xx = 0;
                    String testStr = "";
                    foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dinfo)
                    {
                            if (d != null)
                            {
                                    //testStr += d.Root + "  |  " + d.Parent + "  |  " + d.FullName + "♣";
                                    xx++;
                            }
                    }
                    //testStr += "♣♣ # of Directories found:" + xx;
                    //File.WriteAllText(@"C:\t.txt",testStr.Replace("♣",Environment.NewLine));

                    MessageBox.Show(xx.ToString());
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: @ChrisBallard Added the relevant part of my code

Comment: can you post all of it - things such as `tempDirectoryInfo` missing, so I can't really find your starting point

Comment: @ChrisBallard Sure, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to jump the gun and assume you firstly want to get a single list of all directories beneath a given path (recursively). This code should do that:

```
string[] allDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

or if you need all files based on a pattern, just go with:

```
string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

**EDIT:**

If you have trouble with `UnauthorizedAccessException`, you can roll your own implementation using LINQ and recursion, such as:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> MyGetDirectories(string basePath)
{
    try
    {
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(basePath);
        return dirs.Union(dirs.SelectMany(dir => MyGetDirectories(dir)));
    }
    catch(UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
}
```

Which you can call (and turn back to an array) with something like:

```
string[] allDirs = MyGetDirectories(@"D:\").ToArray();
```

**Supporting Multiple Base Paths**

If you have an array with multiple base paths, we can use `SelectMany` again to get everything in one list, so:

```
string[] basePaths = new string[] { @"C:\", @"D:\" };
string[] allDirs = basePaths.SelectMany(dir => MyGetDirectories(dir)).ToArray();
```

The meaning of this is that for each item in `basePaths`, we will use that entry to select many matching items (in this case by calling `MyGetDirectories`) and then everything is joined together into one big list. In the last step this is converted back into an array.

Comment: Whow... well if doing the recursive search is that simple then I'm probably just wasting my time reinventing the wheel... I'll try this out! Thanks

Comment: .NET has so many nooks and crannies - easy to miss features like that :)

Comment: The thing is though, I'm trying to understand your code (it's still a bit over my head) but i have an array of base paths, the problem with that is, that your first solution works great but can't handle the `UnauthorizedAccessException`, and the second one i can'T make to work with multiple base paths

Comment: sorry about that, I used some LINQ trickery! modified to include example for multiple base directories - let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks for all the help! In the end i found it simpler to go with the code i wrote just because of these reasons, but your help is appreciated, it'll probably help me out a lot next time. also i think i figured what was wrong. Every time it hit a directory it couldn't read it skipped a whole bunch just because of how i wrote my code... 

Thanks, again!